# Removing all children of a node while keeping a reference to the parent in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in Firebase (this is but a small sample of a larger structure):

[image]

I'd like to be able to remove all the children of `employees` node and keep the reference to it.
I noticed that if I remove all the children of a node, the parent gets removed as well.

Something like: (After all children are removed)

[image]

Is there any way to keep the reference?

Comment: Why do you wan't to keep the reference if there is no more data in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("employees").removeValue();
```

This will remove the whole node, then you can do:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("employees").setValue(0);
```